# Perl disable Archive::Extract erro rmessages

Tags: perl, extract, archive

In `Perl` I have below lines

```
my $hu_unzip = Archive::Extract->new( archive => $dest_path.'\one.zip' );
my $ok1 = $hu_unzip->extract( to => $dest_path );
my $rse_unzip = Archive::Extract->new( archive => $dest_path.'\two.zip' );
my $ok2 = $rse_unzip->extract( to => $dest_path );
```

But when i run i am getting below message but still `unzip` happens properly.

> format error: bad signature: 0x00000a00 at offset -1 in file E:\Folder\New\one.zip Archive::Zip::_readSignature('IO::File=GLOB(0x23f9644)'

Here i don't want this `error` to be printed. 
So how shall i proceed

Comment: You should have read the documentation of Archive::Extract before posting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `$Archive::Extract::WARN` to false.

The documentation states:

> This variable controls whether errors encountered internally by Archive::Extract should be carp'd or not.
>   Set to false to silence warnings. Inspect the output of the error() method manually to see what went wrong.